# get controller and action name in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to access the name of the current controller and the current method to pass it to my view as a variable.
I've tried several ways from pointers I found online but they don't work so I assume they were for Laravel 3.

Here is what I've tried

```
Request::$route->controller
```

gives

```
Access to undeclared static property: Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::$route
```

and

```
Request::route()->controller
```

gives

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Http\Request::route()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Router` instance in each Request has the following methods that may be of use:

```
/**
 * Retrieve the entire route collection.
 * 
 * @return \Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection
 */
public function getRoutes()
{
    return $this->routes;
}

/**
 * Get the current request being dispatched.
 *
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request
 */
public function getRequest()
{
    return $this->currentRequest;
}

/**
 * Get the current route being executed.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Routing\Route
 */
public function getCurrentRoute()
{
    return $this->currentRoute;
}

/**
 * Get the controller inspector instance.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Routing\Controllers\Inspector
 */
public function getInspector()
{
    return $this->inspector ?: new Controllers\Inspector;
}
```

Comment: How do you access the `Router` instance?

Answer (score 10):

```
Route::currentRouteAction()
```

returns e..g "RecordAPIController@show"

Answer (score 7):

Try naming your routes as per the [route docs](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#named-routes) and then using `$name = Route::currentRouteName();`

In what condition do you not know what Controller / Route is being fired ahead of time? Can you let us know your use case is?

Answer (score 1):

Laravel used "Request" as alias for 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request' (can be found in app.php).
My advices is to avoid using "Request" as your model/controller/view name.

Answer (score -3):

You could use basic php constants / functions, rather than Laravel:

```
__LINE__, __FILE__, __FUNCTION__, __CLASS__, __METHOD__
```

will give you current line, file, function, class or method

```
get_class()
```

gives you the current class

Comment: This does not produce the correct result in Laravel/Blade.